# How to convert c/c++ callback functon to delphi

Tags: c++, c, delphi, dll, callback

```
typedef void (*onPaymentResultCallback) (int result);

DLL_EXPORT int AR_payment_item_credit(const char *terminal_no, const char *description, double amount, enum currency_id cid, int receiptid,
                onPaymentResultCallback cb);
```

I convert above definetions like this:

```
TonPaymentResultCallback = procedure(result:LongInt) of object;

function AR_payment_item_credit(HInst:THandle; const TerminalNo:PAnsiChar; const Description:PAnsiChar; Amount:Double; CurrencyId:LongInt;
RecepitID:LongInt; onPaymentResultCallback:tonPaymentResultCallback):LongInt;
var
  MyFunct: function (const TerminalNo:PAnsiChar; const Description:PAnsiChar; Amount:Double; CurrencyId:LongInt;
           RecepitID:LongInt; onPaymentResultCallback:tonPaymentResultCallback): LongInt; cdecl;
begin
  Result := 0;

  MyFunct:=GetProcAddress(HInst,'AR_payment_item_credit');
  if Assigned(MyFunct) then
    Result := MyFunct(TerminalNo, Description, Amount, CurrencyId, RecepitID,onPaymentResultCallback);
end;
```

I know C/C++ dll function converting to Delphi, but callback is new for me. 
Are my definitions correct?

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  They are different languages.  For example, C++ has operator and function overloading which may result in name mangling.

Comment: The C functions look like cdecl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Delphi translation has some errors in it.  Try this instead:

```
type
  TPaymentResultCallback = procedure(AResult: Integer); cdecl;

function ARPaymentItemCredit(HInst: THandle; const TerminalNo: PAnsiChar;
  const Description: PAnsiChar; Amount: Double; CurrencyID: Integer;
  ReceiptID: Integer; onPaymentResult: TPaymentResultCallback): Integer;
var
  MyFunct: function(const TerminalNo: PAnsiChar; const Description: PAnsiChar;
    Amount: Double; CurrencyID: Integer; ReceiptID: Integer;
    onPaymentResult: TPaymentResultCallback): Integer; cdecl;
begin
  @MyFunct := GetProcAddress(HInst, 'AR_payment_item_credit');
  if Assigned(MyFunct) then
    Result := MyFunct(TerminalNo, Description, Amount, CurrencyID, ReceiptID, onPaymentResult)
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

The most important difference from your code is `TPaymentResultCallback` is not declared as `of object`.  You can't use a Delphi-style method pointer as a C-style function pointer, which means you can't use a non-static class method for your DLL callback, at least in this example.

There is a simple workaround, though - store the desired method pointer in a global variable, and then use a private callback function to invoke it, eg:

```
type
  TPaymentResultEvent = procedure(AResult: Integer) of object;

var
  gOnPaymentResult: TPaymentResultEvent;

procedure myPaymentResultCallback(AResult: Integer); cdecl;
begin
  if Assigned(gOnPaymentResult) then
    gOnPaymentResult(AResult);
end;

function ARPaymentItemCredit(HInst: THandle; const TerminalNo: PAnsiChar;
  const Description: PAnsiChar; Amount: Double; CurrencyID: Integer;
  ReceiptID: Integer; onPaymentResult: TPaymentResultEvent): Integer;
type
  TPaymentResultCallback = procedure(AResult: Integer); cdecl;
var
  MyFunct: function(const TerminalNo: PAnsiChar; const Description: PAnsiChar;
    Amount: Double; CurrencyID: Integer; ReceiptID: Integer;
    onPaymentResult: TPaymentResultCallback): Integer; cdecl;
begin
  @MyFunct := GetProcAddress(HInst, 'AR_payment_item_credit');
  if Assigned(MyFunct) then
  begin
    gOnPaymentResult := onPaymentResult;
    Result := MyFunct(TerminalNo, Description, Amount, CurrencyID, ReceiptID, @myPaymentResultCallback)
  end
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

Needless to say, this won't work if you need to have multiple classes calling `ARPaymentItemCredit()` at the same time, thus requiring the DLL to call different methods each time.

*IF* the DLL provides a way to associate a user-defined value with the callback (and your example appears to not have that option, unless there is a separate DLL function for that purpose), things get easier.  You can simply pass (a pointer to) the actual method pointer as that user-defined value, and then your private callback function can invoke it directly.  No global variable is needed, making it re-entrant for multiple events to run in parallel. But that is a big *IF*.

Comment: So which one I prefer  and How about it is usage? Sorry, I am confused. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ErkanK which one you prefer is up to you. Use whatever one works for your situation.

Comment: I tried your definations yesterday, but I stil couldn't solve my problem. First off all I tried second defination. I got "Access Vioaltion" error at myPaymentResultCallback function on begin always. So it didn't solve my problem. But I love this defination.:) The First defination is that always said me with debugger "Variable required". So what is my fault about in this situation

Comment: Sorrrryy. Execuse Me. It is my fault. Your second solution is correct for me. The problem is that "cdecl". I forgot use it for myPaymentResultCallback function in my example. Thank you again